# Zurb Foundation grid or block grid not working with vertical tabs

Tags: html, tabs, grid, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a set of vertical tabs, and when I try and nest in some grid or block grid elements everything seems to overflow outside of the element

i.e the 1,2,3 should be in the right section of the below image
[image]

```
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-8 columns">
    <ul class="tabs vertical" data-tab>
      <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#domainnames">Domain Names</a></li>
      <li class="tab-title"><a href="#webhosting">Web Hosting</a></li>
      <li class="tab-title"><a href="#businesshosting">Business Hosting</a></li>
      <li class="tab-title"><a href="#premiumservices">Premium Services</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-content">
      <div class="content active" id="domainnames">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <h1>{$LANG.domaincheckerchoosedomain}</h1>
            <form method="post" action="{$systemsslurl}domainchecker.php">
                <div class="row collapse">
                  <div class="medium-9 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="domain" placeholder="{$LANG.domaincheckerdomainexample}">
                  </div>
                  <div class="medium-3 columns">
                    {if $condlinks.domainreg}<input type="submit" value="{$LANG.checkavailability}" class="button postfix" /> {/if}
                  </div>
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="webhosting">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="businesshosting">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="premiumservices">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tabs vertical` and `tabs-content` got some special properties to build to vertical navigation structure.

Tab `tabs vertical` got `width: 20%` and `float:left`.

The `.small-block-grid-3` breaks out of this float.

Try:

```
@import "foundation";
.small-block-grid-3 {
margin-left: 20%;
& > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: none;
}
}
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/b3c63c443765c4b7ad56

**update**

> is this a similar issue with the standard grid?

No, i think you should be able to use the standard grid without modifications:

```
<div aria-hidden="false" class="content active" id="panel21">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="small-3 columns">1</div>
  <div class="small-3 columns">2</div>
  <div class="small-3 columns">3</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/29c180401ed433ff2d2d

Comment: is this a similar issue with the standard grid?

Comment: The code you mention in the update breaks if you make them `small-4` instead of `small-3`. Are the vertical tabs always 3 columns?

Answer (score 3):

Tabs content div for vertical tabs need class vertical

replace div class="tabs-content"

with div class="tabs-content vertical"

Comment: This was missing from the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/tabs.html#vertical-tabs).  Thank you